# 2D Unconstrained Nx1 Array

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I'm trying to create a flexible array of constants. I want to use a 2D array which may sometimes be for example a 2x1, 2x2, 3x2 array etc. For example:

```
type int_2d_array is array (integer range<>, integer range<>) of integer;
constant M : positive := 2;
constant nMax : positive := 1;
constant n : int_2d_array(M - 1 downto 0, nMax - 1 downto 0) := ( (1) , (2) ); -- wrong

error: type int_2d_array does not match with the integer literal
```

If I do this, it doesn't complain:

```
type int_2d_array is array (integer range<>, integer range<>) of integer;
constant M : positive := 2;
constant nMax : positive := 2;
constant n : int_2d_array(M - 1 downto 0, nMax - 1 downto 0) := ( ( 0,1 ) , ( 2,2 )); -- accepted
```

Is the first example even possible using a 2D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to compile the first example in the following ugly way:

```
type int_2d_array is array (integer range<>, integer range<>) of integer;
  constant M : positive := 2;
  constant nMax : positive := 1;
  constant n : int_2d_array(M - 1 downto 0, nMax - 1 downto 0) := ( (others => 1) , (others => 2) );
```

Strange behavior, indeed.

Comment: Your answer does not compile with ModelSim

Answer (score 5):

The LRM (section 9.3.3 Aggregates) states:

> Aggregates containing a single element association
>   shall always be specified using **named** association in order to distinguish them from parenthesized expressions.

So, this is OK:

```
constant n : int_1d_array(0 downto 0) := ( 0 => 1 );
```

and this is not:

```
constant n : int_1d_array(0 downto 0) := ( 1 );
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/6a4

Comment: Thanks for the more enlightened comment