# How to assign an array of a custom type of length one in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am using a custom type to define an array of two-bit pairs (std_logic_vector of length 2).
This works fine when assigning multiple pairs, for a single pair however, both GHDL and Vivado throw errors.

Code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
end entity;

architecture RTL of test is
  type bit_pairs is array(natural range<>) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

  -- This works fine
  constant test_vector0 : bit_pairs(1 downto 0) := ("11", "00"); 
  -- This doesn't
  constant test_vector1 : bit_pairs(0 downto 0) := ("11");
  -- This also doesn't
  constant test_vector2 : bit_pairs(0 downto 0) := std_logic_vector'("11");
  -- This works, though seems like workaround / hack, not a real solution
  constant test_vector3 : bit_pairs(0 downto 0) := (others => "11");

  -- [Update - see comments] This works as well
  constant test_vector4 : bit_pairs(0 downto 0) := (0 => "11");

begin
end RTL;
```

GHDL throws this error:

```
test2.vhd:15:55:error: can't match string literal with type the anonymous array subtype defined at test2.vhd:15:38
```

For my use case it is necessary to declare the constant as a vector, so I can't just use a regular std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) in the cases where I only need a single two-bit element.

While I was able to figure out the workaround included in the code example, I would much prefer a less 'hacky' solution for this.

Comment: If a VHDL _aggregate_ has only one element, only _named association_ can be used. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359413/2d-unconstrained-nx1-array/35362198#35362198).

Comment: Another hacky option is to create a constant thats a null array and concatenate it with your option:
constant N : bit_pairs(1 to 0) := (others => "00");
contant test_vector4 : bit_pairs(0 downto 0) := N & "11";
 This is a nice hack to create an unsigned/signed from a std_logic:
op <= some_unsigned_number + ("" & single_bit);

Comment: @Matthew Taylor Thanks for the link, using (0 => "11") to assign the vector works and looks much better than using (others => "11")

Comment: test_vector1, test_vector2, and test_vector 3 are not zero length arrays. They each have one element. (The question title is erroneous.) Length represents the number of valid index values (see null range IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1 General).